# Curl - Multiple Process with same session?

Tags: php, curl

I have written a script in PHP using curl to login on a website and do specific task. It run in the background on Linux.

However, I want to run a second process (eg: process2.php) but how to use same session and cookies without logging into website again?

It is like opening second tab on the same browser.

Comment: use the same cookie jar for both?

Comment: Save them somewhere with shared access - database, serialized file etc

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the same `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` parameter for all of your curl requests, they will share their cookies.

Since PHP by default uses cookies to identify you and your session, the requesting curl client will share that session.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  __DIR__."/cookies/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__."/cookies/cookie.txt");
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Keep in mind though that curl will only update it's cookie parameter on `curl_close()`. So you will have troubles when calling to many such requests at the same time. Classic racing conditions might apply.

Comment: Not sure if you need both parameters. The docs are a bit unclear on that, at least to me. But it will work like this anyways.